# Search multiple tables same column name

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have a database with over a hundred tables consisting of weather records from numerous stations, each table is unrelated but all have several shared column names with the same data set(eg. max temperature for each day). I cannot join the tables as there only a few column names that are consistent across each table (these are the ones I want to use).

I want to be able to search for patterns and values across all the tables (eg. SELECT stationName, date FROM multipleTables where maxTemp > 30) which should return station name and the date across every table where the condition is met.

Each table is structured with columns approx as follows:

StationName | Date| MaxTemp | MinTemp | etc

I'm new to working with SQL and databases so I'm really not sure how to go about this. I already attempted to combine the data into one table but it quickly became messy. I also tried using union and joins but didn't get anywhere.

I'm using mariaDB with phpmyadmin and my raw data is in csv files

Comment: Might be a time to recommend throwing this into Hadoop and letting NoSQL shine.   One table is far preferable, however you can mimic this with a view and a crap ton of unions.   Curious if there is a cleaner solution, but my experience says you are in for a lot of manual work mapping like columns between each table one at a time and unioning it in.  (don't join, use unions.   select 'table1' as tablename, columns_desired from table 1 union select 'table2' as tablename, columns_desired .... etc.  I like leaving the 'tablename' column to help determine what table that record came from)

Comment: @Twelfth "union instead of join" is probably enough for a solid answer.

Comment: "I also tried using union ..." - Please post your attempt with UNION.

Comment: Just do them one by one and build a new table with the results as you go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at Hadoop and NoSQL, I've got a small bit of experience with Firebase but don't know much about NoSQL tbh. The issue I was having with unions was that every table has a different number of columns and some tables have data that I'd like to be queryable that other tables don't have so it just got very messy and confusing, think its still probably my option though its just going to be very tedious and time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

> The following SQL generates the actual queries against all the tables with matching columns, these queries can then be run in sequence as a SQL script
>   and results can be collected -

```
SELECT 
    'SELECT '||U1.COLUMN_NAME||', '||U2.COLUMN_NAME||' FROM '||U1.TABLE_NAME||' WHERE MAXTEMP > 30' 
FROM 
    USER_TAB_COLUMNS U1, USER_TAB_COLUMNS U2
WHERE U1.TABLE_NAME = U2.TABLE_NAME
AND U1.COLUMN_NAME = 'StationName '
AND U2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Date'
;
```

Comment: This is not MariaDB syntax.  See `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`.